# How to replace a single char by index

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i have a date string looks like this : `8/30/1987` 
at this time i can find the index of "/" by scan code.
i want to replace the "/" character with "-". how can i do it?

TNX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your date on a `NSString` object, you can do:

```
NSString *new = [yourDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"/" withString:@"-"];
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, reading the [`NSString` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) will answer questions like this.

For this, you can use the `NSString` method `– stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`